# How to mention paper that we withdrew and another paper under preparation in CV?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, cv

One of my papers have been accepted to a conference for presentation. But we figured that the quality of the conference was quite bad and we wanted to submit it to a good/okay conference in the coming days. But my Master's application deadline is fast approaching and I need to submit my CV.

Moreover, another work of mine is currently at the final stage (draft has been made) for submission in a journal.

How do I meantion this in my CV? Or should I not mention at all? So far I only have one conference paper that I have presented and has been included in the proceedings. Thank you.

Comment: If you do want to mention it, be sure to have a more thorough explanation of why you withdrew it. Deciding after getting it accepted that the conference was not high enough quality seems like it will make you look bad unless it was something related to the acceptance that gave this impression.

Comment: It was indeed related to the acceptance. One of the two reviewers of our paper didn't even bother to leave a single response, while the other just wrote, "Make English good!". The main reason though was, we learned from one of our undergraduate class mates that he was assigned to review the papers delegated to him by his professor (who was a reviewer for the conference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would avoid mentioning the bad-quality conference and the withdrawal.  Mentioning it may send a negative message about your  planning habits, and your willingness to waste peoples' (reviewers') time due to those planning habits.

After re-submitting the paper, you can mention it in your CV if you clearly label it as "submitted". The other, unsubmitted paper can be mentioned as well, with the note "in progress" rather than "submitted".

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a sensible approach. Is it okay if I mention both the papers with "In Progress" notes, since I am submitting both of them soon?

Comment: Sure, this would be fine.